# Changing CSS element

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div object with a property of width = 800. I want to assign the width of this div object to another div object.

```
<div id="object1" style="width: 800px;"></div>

<div id="object2"></div>
```

So as I'm coding on my javascript.js file, I tried to use the clientWidth method but didn't work.

```
var obj1 = document.getElementById("object1");
var obj2 = document.getElementById("object2");

obj2.style.width = obj1.clientWidth;
```

I've also tried using obj1.style.width but didn't work either. How do I change the properties of these objects by using another object's properties?

Comment: Change it to: `obj2.style.width = obj1.clientWidth + 'px';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`obj1.clientWidth` tells you the width in pixels but returns an integer. For the `obj2.style.width` you need to define if it's 'px', '%', 'em'. `obj2.style.width` expects a string like "1200px".

Change your code `obj2.style.width = obj1.clientWidth + 'px';` to add the type of value to pixels.

Answer (score 2):

You need to say 'px' of '%'. It has to be equivalent to the CSS string.

Comment: Thanks everyone! the +"px" worked like a charm! However, oddly enough, it only worked for clientWidth and not style.width

Comment: @Zulu: weird. What browser? I confirmed it in chrome in my console dynamically right on this site.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed to specify the `px`, `em` or `%`

```js
var obj1 = document.getElementById("object1");
var obj2 = document.getElementById("object2");

obj2.style.width = obj1.clientWidth+"px";
console.log(obj2.style.width)
```

```html
<div id="object1" style="width: 800px;"></div>

<div id="object2"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `obj2.style.width = obj1.clientWidth+"px";` or `obj2.style.width = obj1.style.width;`. Both of them works fine for your case.

```js
var obj1 = document.getElementById("object1");
var obj2 = document.getElementById("object2");

obj2.style.width = obj1.style.width;
//obj2.style.width = obj1.clientWidth+"px";
```

```css
div{
  height:50px;
  background:red;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="object1" style="width: 800px;"></div>

<div id="object2"></div>
So as I'm coding on my javascript.js file, I tried to use the clientWidth method but didn't work.
```